# How can I stop my websocket connection from closing?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm new to websockets and asyncio and I'm trying to get a simple example working. I would like to create a server that accepts connections from multiple clients and concurrently runs a loop that sends a message to every connection once a second. I'm also trying to use asyncio.run() which I believe is preferred to the get_event_loop() code on which many examples are based.

Here's my code so far:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

USERS = set()

async def register(websocket, path):
    USERS.add(websocket)
    await websocket.send("Successfully registered")

async def count():
    count = 0
    while True:
        print(f"Iteration: {count}")
        if USERS:
            for user in USERS:
                await user.send("Sending message back to client")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        count +=1

async def serve():
    server = await websockets.serve(register, 'localhost', 8765)
    await server.wait_closed()
    print("Server closed")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(count(), serve())

asyncio.run(main())
```

When I run this the count coroutine works until I make a connection from a client. At this point the connection is successfully registered but when I try to send a message back to the client in count() I get an error because the connection is already closed. How should I change my code to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I change my code to stop this from happening?

The problem might be that your handler, the `register` coroutine, is returning immediately, which prompts websockets to close the connection. Try to change it like this:

```
async def register(websocket, path):
    USERS.add(websocket)
    await websocket.send("Successfully registered")
    await asyncio.Event().wait()
```

If that helps, you can put the event in `USERS` along with websocket, so that you have a way to terminate the connection to the client when you want to.